# transitionend with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a background color transition with javascript and I want to port it to use
Jquery, but something is wrong with my code, the Jquery version is cutting the effect, could help me with this?

JS Working Version:

```
var f = document.getElementById('test');
function updateTransition() {
  var el = document.querySelector("span.state1");

  if (el) {
    el.className = el.className.replace("state1","state2");
  } else {
    el = document.querySelector("span.state2");
    el.className = el.className.replace("state2","state1");
  }
  return el;
}
f.addEventListener("transitionend", updateTransition, true);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(updateTransition, 1000);
```

JQUERY Not working Version:

```
$('#test2').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend',function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('state1');
            });
var testi = setInterval(function(){
            $('#test2').toggleClass('state2');
    },1000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MxAX9/27/ 
EDIT: Thanks guys, now I get it...

Comment: Could you please explain what is going wrong in the code? What errors are you getting?

Comment: My jquery version don't run the complete cycle and is cutting the effect in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Quick run through of what this does, really straight forward...

- Checks to see if the function is in state1; otherwise from what you have told it will be in state2
- Remove current class, and add updated class.

Just do:

```
setInterval(function(){$('#testy')
    if($('#testy').hasClass('state1')){
        $('#testy').removeClass('state1').addClass('state2');
    }
    else{
        $('#testy').removeClass('state2').addClass('state1');
    }
   },1000);
```

You can change the interval as you see fit.

If you want to make a function out of it, to respond to events then you can do this:

```
this.transition = function(){
  setInterval(function(){$('#testy')
    if($('#testy').hasClass('state1')){
        $('#testy').removeClass('state1').addClass('state2');
    }
    else{
        $('#testy').removeClass('state2').addClass('state1');
    }
   },1000);
};

$(document).ready(function(){ //will execute on page load; but you can choose to do whatever you like, on click, on hover etc.
    transition();
});
```

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/MxAX9/29/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test2').toggleClass('state2');
```

This will only apply or remove state2 but has no impact on state1 (meaning toggle won't add state1)

You need to do the it yourself:

```
var testi = setInterval(function(){
    var $span = $('#test2');
   if($span.hasClass( "state2" )){
       $span.removeClass("state2").addClass("state1");
   }
   else{
        $span.removeClass("state1").addClass("state2");
    }

},1000);
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MxAX9/30/